# Dynamic subdomain ditection is cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I need to detect subdomain in cakephp. I assume this can be done through .htaccess rules but I'm a newbie and not much knowledge with .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use .htaccess I found the solution using regex.

```
$url = "abc.yourdomain.com";
preg_match('/^(?:www\.)?(?:(.+)\.)?(.+\..+)$/i', $url, $matches);
$subdomain = empty($matches[1])? '' : $matches[1];
```

you will get abc in the subdomain, for www.yourdomain.com or yourdomain.com that will be empty

Comment: Surely `parse_url()` would be a good option to use instead of regex?

Comment: @scrowler - with `parse_url()` 

`$url = 'http://yourdomain.com';` will return `yourdomain`. and www.yourdomain will return www


$url = 'http://yourdomain.com';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);

$subdomain = $host[0];
echo $subdomain;